# Complimentary output function

Tags: r, function

I have to write a code that outputs complimentary bases for DNA sequences, and if the input is not one of the bases it should output "N". I seem to be able to get the complimentary bases, but not the "N" output

```
comp_base <- function(b){
  bases <- c("A","T","C","G")
  comps <- c("T","A","G","C")
  names(comps) <- bases
  cb <- comps[b]
  return(cb)
  if (b == bases){
    comp = cb
  }
  else {
    return("N")
  }
  
}
```

I have attempted a few different ways to get "N"

```
if (b != bases){
comp = "N"
}
```

```
else {
comp = "N"
}
comp
```

and this sort of thing. I still can't get this to work, although I also don't fully see how my code is wrong (please do let me know).

Thanks for any help I can get!!

Comment: Is this for a class assignment? Otherwise, there are libraries that save you having to write this kind of thing such as [Biostrings](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html). Also: are you complementing or reverse-complementing? _i.e._ should "CAA" become "GTT" or "TTG" ?

Comment: It's for a class assignment, so I need to do it a certain way. The complements should be "CAA" to "GTT".